# Expressing recursive sequence

Tags: python, recursion, sequence

[image]

I have that the sequence goes:

```
2, 10, 10, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, ..., a₁₅=130, 17290, ...
```

My function works starting from `n > 3`, otherwise it returns `a₁, a₂, a₃ = 2, 2, 2` when it should be `a₁, a₂, a₃, a₄ = 2, 10, 10, 130`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def s(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    elif math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) == math.floor(math.sqrt(n-1)):
        return s(n-1)
    else:
        return s(n-1) ** 2 + 3 * s(n-1)
```

What's wrong with it?

Note that I'm trying to return the *nth term* of the sequence and not the entire sequence up to n.

Comment: You're missing the `a[…]` or `s(…)` part. `math.floor(math.sqrt(n))` is just going to be `0`, `1`, `2`, etc., not `1`, `10`, `10`, etc.

Comment: SO is not a math-notation-heavy Q&A site, could you explain a bit of the math notation in the image? What are those brackets?

Comment: Why do you have three conditions when there are only two branches to the function?

Comment: Why are you doing the `elif` clause? Also, why do none of the expressions returned in any branch contain a square root or a floor?

Comment: @heltonbiker Those stand for rounding down, i.e. floor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky recursion because it doesn't mention *a*<sub>*n*-1</sub> anywhere like most simple recursive definitions do. That means you shouldn't have any `s(n-1)` references in your code.

In the equation, `floor(sqrt(n))` is the parameter to *a<sub>n</sub>*. Since you call your function `s`, you should therefore be passing `floor(sqrt(n))` to the recursive invocations of `s`.

```
def s(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        x = s(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
        return x**2 + 3*x
```

Since *a*<sub>⌊√*n*⌋</sub> shows up twice, the code above calculates it once and calls that value `x`.

Comment: So this is not actually recursive, but piecewise, isn't it?

Comment: @heltonbiker: Most recursive functions are technically piecewise as well.  You need a base case, or you'll be calling yourself forever.  But as for whether it's recursive...it calls itself, so by definition it is.

Comment: Recursive functions are notated similarly to piecewise functions.